# Is there any working alternatives to Netvizz?

Tags: graphs, social-network-analysis

I'd like to download my friends data as a graph/network from Facebook. In Feb 2015, Facebook banned the awesome application Netvizz. Do you know any alternative application for my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Go for NodeXL [SocialNetImporter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyvwQSTO8Gc) pluggin